# write sql command to text file

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to write sql command to text file with parameter values.
Following is my code for replacing parameter with appropriate values.

```
string commandText = commandInfo.CommandText;

if (commandInfo.Parameters.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (SqlParameter parameter in commandInfo.Parameters)
    {
        commandText=commandText.Replace(parameter.ParameterName,parameter.Value==(object)DBNull.Value?(object)DBNull.Value:("'"+parameter.Value.ToString()+"'"));
    }
}
```

the catch is although all other parameter values are replaced correctly.those having null values are taken up as blank i.e 'parameter1',,'param2'

between the two is the null valued parameter in final string.

What can be the alternative?

Comment: Null is nothing.  Try `(Object)DBNull.Value?"Null":("'"+Parameter.Value....`

Comment: oh my bad.. why did i think putting that way will be taken as 'NULL'..

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, *replacing* the parameters with values is (IMO) the wrong thing to do; what we do in [mini-profiler](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/) is to spoof `declare` statements at the top of the output, so that you can copy and paste it into SSMS, without needing to worry about what is a parameter and what was hard-coded in the original TSQL. For example, glancing at the mini-profiler output for this page, I see

```
DECLARE @id int = 18121022,
        @type tinyint = 10;
```

(and then lots of tsql that is very specific to us)

You can glance at the mini-profiler code to see how we output this, but *basically* it just involves walking over the parameters, writing a simple `declare`. If you are using something like ASP.NET, mini-profiler also avoids the need to write a file (instead making it available live on the site, to your developers).